# Exporting Plone content: how to get the tarball created by quintagroup.transmogrifier.writer

Tags: plone, data-migration, plone-4.x, transmogrifier

I have a transmogrifier pipeline which exports a path from my Plone site (and is supposed to export all *used* resources which are stored in other parts of the site).

The pipeline is pretty standard:

```
[transmogrifier]
pipeline =
    sitewalker
    manifestexporter
    fileexporter
    marshaller
    propertiesexporter
    commentsexporter
    datacorrector
    portletsexporter
    writer
    EXPORTING
```

I can see there is something happening (from `var/log/instance.log`), and finally `quintagroup.transmogrifier.logger` (the `EXPORTING` section) tells me about 83 exported items, which looks good.

I can see that the `quintagroup.transmogrifier.writer` created a `TarballExportContext`; but is is `StringIO` only, and I can't see where it is written to disk, or injected into the pipe to let me return it to the user somehow.

I had a look [on the quintagroup site](http://projects.quintagroup.com/products/wiki/quintagroup.transmogrifier), but two of the three "Articles and Blogs" links are broken.  The [Content migration from Plone 2 to Plone 3](http://projects.quintagroup.com/products/wiki/quintagroup.transmogrifier/plone2-3) page uses the `directory` context.

I'd like to have the tarball, of course; I thought this would be a quite obvious requirement.
How is this supposed to be done?
Is the (default!) `tarball` context broken, and do I need to create my tarball myself (from the directory)?

**Update**:
The `directory` "context" export works and gives me a tree below {site root}/{path option}/{prefix option}.

Comment: Does http://docs.plone.org/develop/plone/content/importexport.html help?

Comment: If this isn't working for you (which surprises me, though I haven't tried it for a long time), then (sorry for the re-iteration) you might want to look at https://collectivejsonify.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ - particulary `get_catalog_results` and "Using the exporter"

Comment: @Danimal: I had a look, but I'm not sure whether it will help me. I need to inject objects into my export (which are referred by their UIDs, and which are a small subset of a distinct tree of fantastillion objects), and - from looking at it - the pipeline of blueprints looks more like it. The problem is the non-functional tarball export, but I could get along with directories for now (and I might fix it in my own fork).

Comment: Ok, so it's still the same general problem as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30885493/how-to-transfer-a-structure-from-one-plone-to-another.   Regarding q.tranmogrifier, does it not just download to your browser's Downloads directory??

Comment: Yes, right; the same general problem. I can watch the tarball getting built, but I can't get it. I have a fork now of q.transmogrifier, but I'm still new to this blueprints/pipeline thing, and don't want to spoil the logic with hacks ... (I might spice it with docstrings, though).

Comment: Hmm, is that the whole pipeline?  Is there not to that file?

Comment: Does [this page](http://projects.quintagroup.com/products/wiki/quintagroup.transmogrifier/plone3-4) help?

Comment: I know this page, of course; my pipeline was copied from it. I tried the export via `Generic Setup Tool` first, but I got an `AttributeError: Transmogrifier instance has no attribute 'configuration_id'`. Then I built my own browser to trigger the export, but I can't see a special section other than `writer` which is supposed to write the tarball to disk.

Comment: "built your own browser"? you mean you've writing your own code that isn't working?

Comment: What happens on step 4 of that process? When you press "Export selected steps"?  What about if you select e.g. javascript registry to export instead?

Comment: My own browser is not at all involved in the crashing code (`configuration_id`); it simply calls a transmogrifier script, after preparing some options. The transmogrifier runs, but it seems there is no way to take the tarball from the pipe. I'll pick it from the `export_context` now, but I didn't test it yet (urgent other things to do today).

Comment: The `Javascript registry` is one of the exports that work; when I try to `Export all steps`, I get a crash (now from the `Transmogrifier`, but I remember other failing exports as well).

Comment: I would stick to trying to debug the crash on the Q.Transmogrifier export step, rather than trying to roll your own transmogrifier runner.  You are going to get more help debugging open source code, which other folk have got working (i.e. q.tm) than your own code which you haven't made available (yet).  Saying that you might try using mr.migrator to see if it works with this export....